# Document type on search displays random numbers

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results

Hi all and thanks in advance.  I have an issue where when doing a search in Sharepoint Online the document type section on the left side bar adds random numbers in front of the document type.  These numbers do not exist in the term store where the doc type is stored. [image: Example]

I am relatively new to sharepoint so any help would be greatly appreciated.

-Jeff

Comment: Is the Document type in the refiner web part one of the RefinableStrings? Pls share the mapping for that fields. You will find the mapping under Site Settings->Search Schema for Site collection

Answer (score 0):

Edit the search result page, and edit Refinement web part, click “Choose Refiners..” button in the Refinement panel.

Check which refiner you have selected for Document Type refiner.

Then go to SharePoint Admin Center->Search->Manage search schema, find out the relevant refiner in the Managed Properties, check which crawled property you selected for map. Check what’s the type of crawled property.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have reviewed what you requested.  Here are the results:   The Refiner used is "refinableString04" for Document Type.  When looking for the managed property "refinableString04" the mapped crawled properties are: ows_Document_x0020_Type, and Document Type  Type for both is text

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a choice field for the Document Type column and the ID is showing. That "usually" does not happen, so I have to ask if you are trying to use a custom Filter Display Template? If so you should try changing it to one of the OOB display templates. If that resolves it ask your developer to account for the item ID and separator characters.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The display template selected in the refiner part is "refinement item" which I believe is ootb.  Is there any way to check or edit this template?

Comment: You can compare the modified date to the others in the folder. It is best not to edit the OOB templates, just create a copy and work with the new renamed copy.